# Is there a selector for odd/even children of a certain class in css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I will try to make my problem as clear as I can, so please bear with me! :)

I have something like the following html. Please note that each div in #container can be repeated any number of time in my application. So it's possible that div.a will not the there, or that I'll have more than one.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="a">1</div>
  <div class="b">2</div>
  <div class="b">3</div>
  <div class="b">4</div>
  <div class="b">5</div>
  <div class="c">6</div>
</div>
```

In the above html, I want a css selector for div #3 and #5. Using div.b + div.b affects all div.b except the first one of the streak. Using div.b:nth-child(even) is starting its count at div #1, so div #2 gets selected and I don't need it to.

What I need is to be able to select all the even div.b in a streak, without being affected by whatever is before or after the streak. And I'd like to avoid using JavaScript. Any idea?

Comment: So you're looking for `.b:nth-of-class(even)`, except using a selector that actually exists?

Comment: what kind of compatibility do you need ?

Comment: Can you alter the html to add `odd` and `even` as additional classes?

Comment: @remibourgarel : I only care about IE 9 and FF / Chrome / Safari current versions.

Comment: @graphicdivine : that is what I want to avoid if I can.

Comment: @thirtydot: yeah exactly! something like that would be very nice ;)

Comment: @Gabriel Sorry, I think you cannot avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding this answer in case someone finds this question from a search engine.

After many hours of research, there is no magical all css answer to this. Don't waste as much time as I did on this, and go with the "odd" and "even" class in the markup. :)

Answer (score 0):

'+' is for the next sibling or adjacent element.  i.e. li + li or h3 + p

but you're not looking for adjacent, you're looking for the nth element.

Comment: can you use jquery instead of trying to do it in the CSS?